# Upgrading Ubuntu Server minimal install

Tags: upgrade

I currently have an Ubuntu Server 13.04 minimal install. If I upgrade when 13.10 is released will it install all of the default packages of Ubuntu Server?

Comment: What do you mean?  Upgrading replaces the packages you currently have with their new versions.  New packages are only installed if they are now required by the new versions of the existing packages being upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special to it. Upgrading works the same for any version of Ubuntu, updated packages get downloaded and replaces the old ones that were installed. Just that. You can even after upgrade install more packages and there will not be any issue.